# Using Multi Layer Perceptron to categorize skills to roles

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron

I have a data set of different roles and their skills. For eg.

```
role: Software Engineer - skills: java, elasticsearch, elixir
role: Software Engineer - skills: python, ruby, solr
role: Frontend Engineer - skills: angularjs, reactjs, html, css
role: UI Designer       - skills: html, css, photoshop
.
.
.
```

Many roles would have overlapping skills. What i want to do is, for a given skill set get the best matching roles in order of relevance.

I used Multilayer perceptron once during college for classification of cars based on different features. Can it be used for this also. Is there a better way to do this. I will have more data coming in to train it.